# Detecting swipe functionality in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, gesture, hammer.js

I'm plannig to add "swipe from edge / swipe from vertical border" gesture functionality to my web application for touch based devices. Possibly I will use [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163202/javascript-touch-movement-track-when-user-swipes-from-edges). But the problem is some browsers has swipe from edge functionality naturally.

For example in Google Chrome for Android's [old versions](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.tr/2013/08/new-gestures-in-chrome-for-android.html), when you swipe from left edge, browser goes to next tab. Swipe from edge makes [UCBrowser](http://www.techinasia.com/uc-browser-update-tab-gestures-android-tablets/) to go next/previous page in current tab. Also [IOS 7](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review) devices go previous/next page in history.

So is it possible to detect whether swipe from edge functionality is activated in browser naturally ? So I can disable the swipe feature for that type of browsers. Or should I check for user agent and disable for that browsers ?

I don't want to override browser's functionality. I want to disable my menus for that type of browsers.

Comment: possibly consider not having swipe from edge but drag page left and right to show content. Ive had good luck with [snap.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/demo/apps/default.html)