# Not scroll when pan left, pan right hammer 2.0.8

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I use the pan of hammer 2.0.8 when user touchstart from edges screen to drag open another div as ScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer IOS. but I can not disable the scroll while dragging my div. Please help me.

Comment: Please show what you try until now

Comment: I followed the instructions here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24164018/7113902
But I use hammer 2.0.8 and it have not dragLockToAxis as version 1.x